# How to transfer the `id` more securely in Rails project?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, ruby, rails

I checked my rails project with a brakeman, and received warning.

> Potentially dangerous key allowed for [mass assignment](https://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/mass_assignment/):
>   params.require(:inspector_id)

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def report_params
    params.require(:report).permit(inspector_id, ...)
  end
end

class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :inspector 
end

class Inspector < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reports
end
```

How to transfer the ID more securely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend on your permissions model. As it stands, a call to `update_attributes` etc. allows anyone with permissions to update a report to also link that report to any inspector. If this is not a privileged operation in your application, e.g. if all your users have the same rights and are supposed to be able to access all records in your database, that might be fine.

Otherwise you'd need to check whether the current user is allowed to establish a link between the specified report and inspector. How that works is of course highly dependent on your application; if you want a nice way to organise your permissions in a central place, I encourage you to have a look at the `cancancan` gem:

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

In any case, the problem is not the way the ID is transferred but that you might need to check it before accepting it into your database.